# How to put a big message on my home and lock screen?

Tags: lock-screens, home-screen

I want to put a big message on my home and lock screen. Something like "don't screw up your diet". You get the idea. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

One way is to just make an image of your wallpaper with the words printed on it and then select the new image as your wallpaper. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In the lock screen you can put a message in **Settings->LockScreen and Security->LockScreen Message**. This way is in my Xperia M5 Android 6.0 but is similar in other phones or android versions

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings> lock screen and then there will be a option to add text on the lock screen!

Comment: That would be neither "big" nor would it show up on Home screen.